# Hover picture positioned under other content

Tags: html, css, hover

i'm trying to add some hover selector for the images of the page i'm currently developing, but as i point the cursor on the image, hover works fine but the position was somehow wrong because it appears under the content close to it. i've tried using z-index and positions. and one more thing, i also want it to zoom from the center of the div, and from the corner . any help?check out this fiddle

```
  CSS:
  html, body { 
  margin: 0; 
   height: 100%; 
   }

.management_wrapper{
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 80%; ;
 height:auto;
 background-color: white;
 padding-top: 0%;
 padding-bottom: 10%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: auto;
 margin-left: 5%; 
 }

#list_box{
margin-top: 1%;
width: 15%;
height:20%;
float:left;
background-color:beige;
margin-right:1%;
position: relative;
}
#info{
margin-top: 1%;
width: 15%;
height:20%;
float:left;
color: white;
margin-right: 1%;
position: relative; 
}
#info p{
margin-top: 20%;
color: ;
}
.img_size {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
}
.img_size:hover{
width: 300px;
height:300px;
position: relative;
}

    HTML:

     <center>   
                    <div id="info" style="background-color: #800000  "></div>   
                    <div id="info" style="background-color: #280000 ;">
                        <p>  Elena H. Dimailig 
                             Managing Director                          </p>    
                    </div>          
                            <div id="list_box">     
                            <center> 
                            <img id="img_size" src="images/main/3.jpg">
                            </center>   
                            </div>  





                <center>    
                    <div id="info" style="background-color: #800000  ">
                        <p>  Joel Molina 
                             Assistant Account Manager                          </p>     
                    </div>                  
                            <div id="list_box">         
                            <center> 
                            <img class="img_size" src="images/main/molina.jpg">
                            </center>   
                            </div>  
                <div id="info" style="background-color: #180000  "></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qz6s2vps/1/

Comment: the url links to the homepage of jsfiddle. pls update it

Comment: please correct url, seems u forgot to add exact url :)

Comment: sorry for that check it again.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the issue, it's unclear to me what the issue is...and update the fiddle to use dummy images

Comment: how can i add dummy images?

Comment: Also `<center>` has beem deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Use placekitten or lorempixel

Comment: Also you seem to be missing some closing tags ***Validate your code***

Comment: @paulie_D  check the new link of jsfiddle i added placekitten thanks

Comment: OK...now fix all the structure problems with the HTML and validate the code...I see you are re-using IDs...you can't do that.

Comment: i'll change it to class. don't worry. any more suggestion why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, than it might be help you, please check it out working demo:

I just modify your demo at: https://jsfiddle.net/223ye3na/

I just modify your below code:

```
#img_size {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;

}
#img_size:hover{
-webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

**Updated:**

After your comments on this answer I was updated my answer check this URL to see live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/223ye3na/1/

**Updated code:**

```
#info{
  z-index: -1;    
}
```

Comment: yes it did solve the problem that i have to make the picture zoom from the center. but as you can see, when you hover the image,the box next to it (the box with joel molina name) is on top of the image. how can i fix that? thanks for another help.

Comment: So exactly what you want to do ?

Comment: i need the hovered picture to be on top of the other contents.